# How to select the all the permutations

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, math, permutation

I want to get a list of all permutations or ranks of permutations where the `ith` element is `k` and the len is greater than `k` and labeled with `n`. A list of integers from `1..n` should be permuted. How Can this be done?

For the first Element of the permutation its trivial. But how does it work for `ith` Element? Iterating through `n!` permutations is not an option.

Comment: What exactly does "labeled with `n`" mean in this context?

Comment: `n` is just the len of the permutation

Comment: And what is supposed to be permuted? A list of integers from `1` to `n` or something else?

Comment: Yes i updated the description

Comment: Fixing `p[i] == k` still means you're going to have `(n-1)!` permutations in your list. If `n!` is too many, are you sure `(n-1)!` isn't also too many?

Comment: Seems like an odd thing to want. What do you want this for?

Comment: Yes because i want to combine more fixed `p[i]==k1, p[i+1]==k2,...`. All together. So that i have in the end serveral `k`th and `i`th. Iam pretty sure there is a pattern so that i can archive this by reusing the Basic algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, notice that this problem can easily be transformed into just ranking/listing permutations.  All that you need to do is write a function that takes a permutation of `1..(n-1)` and transforms it into a permutation meeting your condition, and vice versa.  (Going one way just increment every number in the permutation that is bigger than `k` and insert `k` in the `i`th position.  Going the other remove the `k` and decrement everything larger than `k`.)

But ranking/listing is a well-understood problem.  See https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Permutations/Rank_of_a_permutation for solutions in multiple languages, including three in Python.

This idea can be extended to more conditions like the first.  You just need to write more general transforms first.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: the length of `permutations` is `(n-1)!`, and the total size of `permutations` is O(`n*(n-1)!`).

```
import itertools
i,k,n = 1,5,10 #pick these
permutations = [p for p in itertools.permutations(list(range(1,n+1,1))) if p[i]==k]
```

Comment: @kaya3 That was only added in an edit to the question after my answer was posted. I can read :)

Comment: My mistake, I should have checked the timestamp.